# Can a WordPress site interact with a separately hosted React site with a session storage hook?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, session, react-hooks, session-storage

Forgive me if I use the wrong jargon as my knowledge with React is little to none.

We have a WordPress site hosted through Kinsta and a separate React site hosted on our own servers. This React site is what customers use to log in and access their portal. On the WordPress site, we just have buttons linking to that React site when customers want to log in.

We have an issue where customers coming from the WordPress site will log in, then click on a link that takes them back to the WordPress site for a blog, and they try to go back to their account but need to log in each and every time they leave and try to re-enter the React site.

This is the part that I'm unfamiliar with. A solution that was brought up was to implement a session storage hook. My question is, would it be possible for that session storage hook from the React site to follow the user to the WordPress site/can the two sites interact with each other in that way?

Comment: Is React app written only in JavaScript? Do you have some kind of Backend code like in WordPress? The login should not happen in JavaScript, login to be secure needs to be done on the server. And in order to share login between two applications you can use JWT tokens. If your React App is only in JavaScript (that is not wise) you can save the token in sessionStorage. And to send a JWT token from WordPress to React you can put a token in the URL or use the form and send a POST request to the ReactJS app, but it will require a backend.